# Bokeh: Data Table and Tap Tool not working together

Tags: python, bokeh

I have the following problem when using bokeh's TapTool and DataTable together:

As soon as one dot is clicked (TapTool used), selections on the DataTable do no longer get represented in the plot anymore.

Here is the minimal example for a Jupyter Notebook:

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_notebook, figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, OpenURL, TapTool
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
            x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            y=[6, 7, 2, 4, 5],
            url=["http://www.stackoverflow.com"]*5))

p = figure(plot_width=400, 
           plot_height=400,
          tools="tap,reset",
          )

p.circle(source=source, 
         x="x", 
         y="y", 
         size=20, 
         color="navy", 
         alpha=0.5)


columns = [
    TableColumn(field="x", title="X-Value"),
    TableColumn(field="y", title="Y-Value"),
    TableColumn(field="url", title="URL")
]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns,
                      width=400, height=400)


url = "@url"
taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)

output_notebook()
show(column(p, widgetbox(data_table)))
```

Expected behaviour: Selections from the DataTable get represented in the plot like before clicking one dot.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. This was an issue in bokeh 0.13
With anaconda I couldn't update to 1.0.1, so I created a new environment, where bokeh can be 1.0.1 an the problem no longer exists.